# Selecting a Menu Item with Hammerspoon

Tags: hammerspoon

I try to use Hammerspoon to open a new window in Firefox with the following script:

```lua
function newWindow() 
    local app = hs.application.find("Firefox")
    
    print(hs.inspect.inspect(app))
    print(app:title())
    print(app:bundleID())

    local item = app:findMenuItem("File")
    
    print(item)
end

hs.hotkey.bind({'alt', 'ctrl', 'cmd'}, 'n', newWindow)
```

While the script is able to find Firefox, it is not able to find the menu item I am looking for. But at the same time, I am able to use `app:getMenuItems()` to retrieve the whole menu structure.

Does anyone have an idea why or an working example for any application?

*I am using MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `app:selectMenuItem()` method:

```lua
function newWindow() 
    local app = hs.application.find("Firefox")
    app:selectMenuItem({"File", "New Window"})
end
hs.hotkey.bind({'alt', 'ctrl', 'cmd'}, 'n', newWindow)
```

### From the docs:

`hs.application:selectMenuItem(menuitem[, isRegex]) -> true or nil`

Selects a menu item (i.e. simulates clicking on the menu item)

#### Parameters:

- **menuitem** - The menu item to select, specified as either a string or a table. See the menuitem parameter of hs.application:findMenuItem() for more information.
- **isRegex** - An optional boolean, defaulting to false, which is only used if menuItem is a string. If set to true, menuItem will be treated as a regular expression rather than a strict string to match against

#### Returns:

True if the menu item was found and selected, or nil if it wasn't (e.g. because the menu item couldn't be found)

#### Notes:

Depending on the type of menu item involved, this will either activate or tick/untick the menu item

http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.application.html#selectMenuItem

-- EDIT --

To avoid multiple language menu structure you can also open the new window using the keyboard shortcut for that:

```lua
function newWindow() 
    local app = hs.application.find("Firefox")
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({'cmd'}, 'N', nil, app)
end
hs.hotkey.bind({'alt', 'ctrl', 'cmd'}, 'n', newWindow)
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me if Firefox is already running, if not it won't open it. If you want the script to open it you can use `hs.application.open("Firefox")` when `app`  is nil. However, with the hotkey selected ALT+CMD+CTRL+N, on my machine, it opens Firefox in troubleshoot mode, but if I change `N` to `O` it works just fine.

Comment: FYI, I am using hammerspoon Version 0.9.90

Comment: I tried it. It is not working for Firefox, but for Sublime Text. I run the German localization of Firefox, while Sublime offers only an English UI. Maybe this might be the reason? Which language to you use for Firefox?

Comment: I use it in English. And I got you, I tried to use it in German and the `{"Datei", "­Neues Fenster"}` menu doesn't work, however the `{"Datei", "­Neues privates Fenster"}` works as expected. To avoid the language issues I edited my answer to include an option that uses the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Interessting, this methods works for Slack and Thunderbird in German. I will try it these days with the shortcut